# How could I "re-align" grease pencil vertexes on one axis?

Tags: vertices, grease-pencil, axis

let's say I have this line:

[image]

How could I "re-align" vertexes on one axis so it would become a line ?
On a regular mesh, I would have set the pivot point to 3D cursor, then scale X 0; and points would have been aligned.

But with the Grease Pencil, it seems it also affect the "strength" of the vertexes, my line is loosing it :

[image]

How else could I do ?

Thanks !

Comment: Well this is strange because when I use S+0 on grease pencil, my stroke doesn't loose it's "strength"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck **Stroke** → **Scale Thickness**:

[image]

Comment: That is wonderful !  Thanks.